# Is there a way to use DNSMasq and BIND on the same computer?

Tags: dns, bind, dnsmasq

I like the idea of running my own nameserver (BIND) but if I do that, I can't get the benefit of blocking nasty websites by putting them in /etc/hosts

DNSMasq is able to refer to /etc/hosts but rather than specifying an "upstream" dnsserver, I'd like it to be able to use BIND on the same machine. However, they both need to use the same port.

Is this possible? I couldn't find anything about this in regular searching.

I suppose an alternative would be to run another Linux instance in a VM and run DNSMasq there (say) but I'd like to not have to do this.

Comment: "rather than specifying an "upstream" dnsserver, I'd like it to be able to use BIND on the same machine."  upstream server can be on the same machine, but on a different port. dnsmasq configuration allows specifying a port the upstream nameserver is queried on.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. In the future, ask questions similar to this there.

Comment: Well, you only waited 9 years!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could assign multiple ip addresses to the same interface, either with

```
ip addr add <address>/32 dev eth0
```

or using

```
ifconfig eth0:1 <address>
```

then bind one server to one address, the other server to the second address.
Which server is queried depends now on the ip address your queries are sent to.

The examples assume that your eth interface is eth0.

Comment: So which is better? It seems like it would be easier to assign multiple IP addresses (which I didn't know you could do) than to mess with the ports.

Comment: ifconfig you have already installed, ip you may need to add. ifconfig gives you an additional interface name, ip just adds another ip address. If you specify service binding by interface name, rather than by ip address, ifconfig may have an advantage. ip is, as tool, more powerful than ifconfig.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I really like dnsmasq handling of /etc/hosts and appending a local domain but don't want to use a specific upstream nameserver which I would guess at least google would count who gets the most hits and I'd like to cache replies. I had good results setting up caching bind with root nameservers on one machine and then pointing my other machines with dnsmasq there. At home I only have one machine so got the idea to add an alias and bind bind9 to that.

So the tricky part is that dnsmasq by default binds to all interfaces when it starts so to fix this.

1. Add an alias in /etc/network/interfaces

auto enp2s0

allow-hotplug enp2s0

iface enp2s0 inet static

address 192.168.12.7

network 192.168.12.0

netmask 255.255.255.0

broadcast 192.168.12.255

gateway 192.168.12.1

dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1,9.9.9.9

auto enp2s0:0

allow-hotplug enp2s0:0

iface enp2s0:0 inet static

address 192.168.12.53/24

2. Configure /etc/bind/named.conf.options

listen-on { 192.168.12.53; };

3. Configure DNSMasq file /etc/dnsmasq.conf

except-interface=enp2s0:0

bind-interfaces

Just change interface names and IP's where appropriate.